# How to get Row in Column in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this view in my sql database:

[image]

I have this values in my View with IdEsame = 39

```
    ID  IdEsame IdParametro Ordinamento Colonna
    72  39      163         1           1
    73  39      164         1           2
    74  39      165         1           3
    75  39      166         2           1
    76  39      167         2           2
    77  39      168         2           3
    78  39      169         3           1
    79  39      170         3           2
    80  39      171         3           3
```

Now I want to build a query to set the row in column by Ordinamento Column.

So this query that return this result set

```
ID  IdEsame IdParametro IdParametro2    IdParametro3
72  39      163         164             165
73  39      166         167             168
74  39      169         170             171
```

Comment: How is the first column calculated?  What database are you using?

Comment: I use TSQL as database. The column Ordinamento set the ROW of ResultSet, and Colonna identified the Column of the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TRY THIS**: The solultion would be dynamic `PIVOT` as below but id will return the `minimum` of every set of `Ordinamento` and I hope you also want the same

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(ID INT,  IdEsame INT, IdParametro INT, Ordinamento INT, Colonna INT)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES
(72,39,163,1,1),
(73,39,164,1,2),
(74,39,165,1,3),
(75,39,166,2,1),
(76,39,167,2,2),
(77,39,168,2,3),
(78,39,169,3,1),
(79,39,170,3,2),
(80,39,171,3,3)

DECLARE @col VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(2000)

SELECT @col = 
    COALESCE(@col + ', ','') + QUOTENAME('IdParametro' + CAST(Colonna AS VARCHAR))
FROM #temp
GROUP BY Colonna

SET @sql = '
SELECT t.ID, IdEsame, ' + @col + '
FROM (SELECT 
        IdEsame, 
        IdParametro,
        CONCAT(''IdParametro'',Colonna) AS Colonna,
        Ordinamento
    FROM #temp)p
PIVOT(MAX (IdParametro) FOR Colonna IN ( ' + @col + ' )
) AS pvt
OUTER APPLY( SELECT MIN(id) AS ID 
            FROM #temp t WHERE t.Ordinamento = pvt.Ordinamento) t'

EXEC (@sql)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
ID  IdEsame IdParametro1    IdParametro2    IdParametro3
72  39      163             164             165
75  39      166             167             168
78  39      169             170             171
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses conditional aggregation:

```
select min(id), idesame,
       max(case when colonna = 1 then IdParametro end) as IdParametro1,
       max(case when colonna = 2 then IdParametro end) as IdParametro2,
       max(case when colonna = 3 then IdParametro end) as IdParametro3
from t
group by Ordinamento, idesame;
```

I don't understand how the first column is assigned.  The numbers seem rather arbitrary, but I'm speculating that you want the minimum id for each row.

Comment: Your query it is good but If I have 4 record for every row? in this case I must change the query, I would link to write a query that works never other changes

Comment: @bircastri . . . If you don't know the number of columns in the result set, you need to use dynamic SQL.